# DynamoDB Stream: Last Processing result: PROBLEM: Function call failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Purpose:
My goal is to add items into dynamo using a lambda function, which then will set off another lambda trigger that will send a SNS notification.

The first lambda function successfully adds in items into Dynamo. However the second lambda trigger is not sending SNS notifications.

However, I did a JSON test event for the second lambda trigger and it was then successfully able to send a sns notification. So, theres is something wrong with dynamo and the second lambda function.

In DynamoDB, under 'DynamoDB stream details' where I enabled the lambda tigger I get an error 'PROBLEM: Function call failed'

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451311/dynamodb-trigger-lambda-function-problem-function-call-failed

Comment: @jarmod I tried the suggestions from that link and everything seems to be good on that side. The Dynamo and lambda are not communicating with one another for some reason, and still stuck on figuring out why